# Solutions to $x \exp(x) = a x + b$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

Are there any closed form solutions to 
$$
x \exp(x) = a x + b
$$
for real-valued $x$, $a$, and $b$ (we wish to solve for $x$, and $a$ and $b$ are simple constants)?  We can assume that everything is positive.

I know that the solution to
$$
x \exp(x) = b
$$
can be expressed via the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and
$$
x \exp(x) = a x
$$
is a simple log, but I can't get anything out of there.

Comment: The solution to the last equation is simple log _in addition to_ $x=0$. Don't forget that.

Comment: I suspect no closed form using $W$, but cannot prove. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511558/two-exponential-terms-equation-solution?rq=1) is very tangentially related.

Comment: If $b\approx0$, or close enough to $0$ where $a$ "dominates" the value of the LHS, then the solution is almost $x\approx\ln(a)$.  If $a\approx0$, then the same argument gives $x\approx W(b)$.  Not to much you can do if neither are the case.

Answer (score 1):

$$xe^x=ax+b$$

Your equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an algebraic equation in dependence of $e^x$ and $x$. Because the terms $e^x,x$ are algebraically independent and the equation is irreducible, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
A theorem of Lin (1983) proves, if Schanuel's conjecture is true, that irreducible algebraic equations involving both $e^x$ and $x$ don't have solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$\frac{x}{ax+b}e^x=1$$
$$\frac{x}{x+\frac{b}{a}}e^x=a$$
$$\frac{x}{x-(-\frac{b}{a})}e^x=a$$

We see, your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

$$x=W\left(^{\pm 0}_{-\frac{b}{a}};a\right)$$

The inverse relation of your kind of equations is what Mezö et al. call $r$-Lambert function. They write:
"Depending on the parameter $r$, the $r$-Lambert function has one, two or three real branches and so the above equations can have one, two or three solutions"

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)