# Solving for $u$ after using Lambert W Function substitution.

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511558/two-exponential-terms-equation-solution?rq=1). I understand the given answer except for one particular point in the solution.

The answerer uses a particular substitution:
$x=-W(u)$

They then proceed to manipulate in a chain of steps, upon which one equality is: $[e^{W(u)}]^{-1}=[\frac{u}{W(u)}]^{-1}$.

I have been shown that this stems from
$W(u)e^{W(u)}=u \Rightarrow e^{W(u)}=\frac{u}{W(u)}$,
which now makes sense to me.

Were we to make such a substitution into an equation, how would we go about knowing what value of $u$ to use? Are there a number of $u$ that could work, and if so, how do we choose the best value?

Let's see if I can make my question a little more concrete with an example.

Say I want to solve: $x+ae^{(\frac{b}{x})}=c$

were $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants. I can multiply both sides by $e$ to get

$e^x\cdot e^{ae^{(\frac{b}{x})}}=e^c$

then I can substitute the property from above to get

$\frac{W(u)}{u}e^{ae^{(\frac{b}{x})}}=e^c$

moving $\frac{W(u)}{u}$ to the other side and taking the natural log of both sides I get

$ae^{(\frac{b}{x})}=c\ln \left(\frac{u}{W(u)}\right)$

dividing by $a$ and taking the natural log again I get

$\frac{b}{x}=\ln \left(\frac{c}{a}\ln \left(\frac{u}{W(u)}\right)\right)$

rearranging for x, I get

$x=\frac{b}{\ln \left(\frac{c}{a}\ln \left(\frac{u}{W(u)}\right)\right)}$

Now that I have used the Lambert W function to help isolate $x$, how could I proceed to find $u$ and $W(u)$. I have yet to uncover a resource explaining it, so I request help from someone willing to

- provide a reference link or suggestion that will teach me how to solve this and other explain other intricacies of the Lambert W function
- point out my misgivings and suggest an alternative method to solve the equation (should one exist), linking a similar problem should they know of one
- explain in an answer how one would go about finding $u$

Comment: $$W(u)e^{W(u)}=u\implies e^{W(u)}=\frac{u}{W(u)}$$

Comment: @FShrike Thanks. That was what I was my other thought. I'm new to these, so still feeling my way around. Do you know of a question where they discuss how you would solve for the value of such a substitution? Do I need to develop a new question for that?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking, sorry. You said you understood the rest of the answer in the post you linked; you should edit this question to make it more specific now that you understand the substitution, or put it in a new post

Comment: @FShrike Thanks. I have updated my question. although I still feel it is rather ambiguous and not as clear as I would like. Perhaps that stems from my ignorance of the subject matter.

Comment: Usually if one makes a substitution like $x=-W(u)$, it is not because we know what $u$ is but rather that we expect $u$ to be easier to find (and once $u$ is found, $x$ follows)

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for clarifying. You have really helped me hone my question. I have rewritten with an example, hoping this clarifies a bit more without revealing too many misgiving on my part.

Comment: Much clearer! I’ll post an answer shortly (hopefully...)